# Mechanical Turk: how to allow each turker to do just one hit while allow more than one turker to do the same hit?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Hi I am new to Mechanical Turk.  I have 10k images and I want to ask turkers to write down a short summary for each image in Mechanical Turk. Since all images in my image set are similar, when a Turker does the similar summarization task more than 10 times, he'll find out some tricks in this task and write down similar summary of the following images.

To increase the diversity and randomness, I want to ask as many different people to do the task as possible.  The perfect strategy is that one unique turker is only allowed to label just one image (or less than 10 images), while one image can be summarized by more than one turker. My experiment aims at collect different textual summarization from different people which covers a rich vocabulary set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. According to documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/amt-dg.pdf (page 4)

> You can specify the maximum number of assignments that any Worker can accept for your HITs.You
>   can set two types of limits:

- The maximum number of assignments any Worker can accept for a specific HIT type you've created
- The maximum number of assignments any Worker can accept for all your HITs that don't otherwise
  have a HIT-type-specific limit already assigned

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have unique images in total to label. It sounds like you're looking to have each task (HIT) request that a Worker label 10 unique images. This will result in 1K HITs with 10 images per HIT. If you'd like one just one unique Worker to label each image, then you'll set the Number of Assignments Requested to 1. If you'd like for multiple Workers to work on the same image (say, to ensure quality, or just to broaden the number and type of labels you might get) then you'll set Number of Assignments Requested to the # of Unique Workers you'd like to work on each task (HIT).

If I've misunderstood what you're looking to do, just clarify and I'll be happy to revise my answer.

You can learn more about these concepts and more here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/RequesterUI/mechanical-turk-concepts.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Let me clarify a little bit. Suppose I have 10k images to be summarized -- I'll ask turkers to write a short summary of each image. When a Turker does the similar task more than 10 times, he'll find out some tricks in this task, and write down similar summary of the following images.  To increase the diversity and randomness, I would ask as many people to do the task as possible.  The perfect strategy is that one unique turker is only allowed to summarize just one image, while one image can be summarized by more than one turker.

Comment: In that case, you'll have 10K HITs (one HIT = one Human Intelligence Task = one image) and you'll decide how many Workers you want to work on a single image (which are called Assignments in MTurk). You said you want "as many people as possible" which means you can request a large number of Assignments. Keep in mind your cost is the Number of Assignments * Number of HITs. Hope that helps!